# Swift: Detect swiping across SCNNode

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, swipe, scnnode

Is there any way to detect when the user swipe across [SCNNode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode)? 
I ve already tried [UISwipeGestureReconizer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizer) but it didn't work for me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a pan gesture recognizer

```
    let panRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(panGesture))
    panRecognizer?.delegate = self
    view.addGestureRecognizer(panRecognizer!)
```

Depending if you want to know which direction you'll have to check out the translation of the view.

```
    @objc func panGesture(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer){
        let translation = sender.translation(in: sender.view)
        print(translation.x, translation.y)
    }
}
```

Make sure you have you add the delegate - UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
Hope that gives you a good start